# Oracle: How to query all rows without parent noe-to-one, but if any reference - avoid?

Tags: oracle

Having *USER* and *ADDRESS* (*ADDRESS.USERID -> USER.ID*).

I need to query all users by ID without an address.
But if there any address row (by some criteria), then same user needs to be avoided. Cant figure out.

Already have a code for second criteria. It returns all users without specific address

```
SELECT    
    USER.ID "ID",    
    USER.NAME "NAME",    
FROM 
    USERS USR  
WHERE 
    (
      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ADDRESS ADDR WHERE ADDR.USERID = USR.ID AND (ADDR.CODE NOT LIKE 'A%')) 
    )
    AND USER.NAME LIKE '%USR%'
```

Cant figure out how to extend this query so that users LIKE '%USR%' without any referenced address are also available.

Comment: I don't understand. Your query selects all users whose names contain the string 'USR' and have an address with a code that starts with something else than A. But this is not what you want? What do you want instead? It may help, if you show some sample data, so we get the idea.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, in case if that same user has no address at all, it hsould be available in a query. But if there is a specific address - eliminated from result set.

Comment: Still, no, sorry. If a username contains 'USR', you want that user always, sometimes or never? If a user has no address, you want that user always, sometimes or never? If a user only has address codes starting with A, you want that user? If a user only has address codes not starting with A, you want that user? If a user has some address codes starting with A, some without, you want that user? Please describe exactly which combinations you want and which not.

Answer (score 0):

Here. Doing minus operation should solve the issue, as we already know the users which already has the address... we have to do "all users" minus "users who already have address".

```
SELECT    
    USR.ID "ID",    
    USR.NAME "NAME",    
FROM 
    USERS USR
MINUS
SELECT    
    USR.ID "ID",    
    USR.NAME "NAME",    
FROM 
    USERS USR  
WHERE 
    (
      EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ADDRESS ADDR WHERE ADDR.USERID = USR.ID AND (ADDR.CODE NOT LIKE 'A%')) 
    )
    AND USR.NAME LIKE '%USR%'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is sad we don't have some of your data to test it on. Here is how I'd solve that

```
SELECT USER.ID "ID",    
       USER.NAME "NAME",    
  FROM USERS USR 
  LEFT JOIN ADDRESS ADDR 
    ON ADDR.USERID = USR.ID AND (ADDR.CODE NOT LIKE 'A%')
 WHERE ADDR.CODE IS NULL      -- avoid users that have an adress
    OR USER.NAME LIKE '%USR%' -- users LIKE '%USR%' without any referenced address are also available.
```